# Write a condition inside a sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a column call isDifFromother which is hold either 1 or 2 (default it is set to 0).
when i updating a row, i want to set 2 if the isDifFromother value is having 0.
if its having 1 i want to keep it as it is.

How can i check that condition inside my update query.

here is my query...,

```
UPDATE `customer` SET `name`='" + name + "', `isPackage`='" + packageID + "', `billing_ID`='" + biling_ID + "', `isDifFromother`=IF customer.isDifFromother = '1'  THEN '2' END IF WHERE `id`='" + cusID + "';
```

but its embedded with errors.

Comment: when isDifFromother=0 you want to update isDifFromother as 2 rite ?
update  customer set isDifFromother=2 where isDifFromother=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement is not correct and it should be as

```
UPDATE `customer` SET `name`='" + name + "', `isPackage`='" + packageID + "', `billing_ID`='" + biling_ID + "', `isDifFromother`=IF(customer.isDifFromother = '0','2',customer.isDifFromother) WHERE `id`='" + cusID + "';
```

The following condition

```
`isDifFromother`=IF(customer.isDifFromother = '0','2',customer.isDifFromother)
```

sets isDifFromother = 2 if its 0 else remain as it is.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? or its not updating the data ?

Comment: Have you added like `isDifFromother=IF(customer.isDifFromother = '0','2',customer.isDifFromother)`